# How to optimize or speed up my subquery in mysql or in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery, query-optimization

Sample query:

```
 SELECT 
     table1.t1_id,table1.name,
     table2.address,
     (
         SELECT message 
         FROM table3 
         WHERE logid =  table1.t1_id 
               AND message NOT LIKE "[ SYSTEM%" 
         ORDER BY logs 
         DESC LIMIT 1
     ) as message   
 FROM table1 
 INNER JOIN table2 
 ON table1.t1_id = table2.t2_id   
 WHERE table1.dateCreated   
 BETWEEN CAST('2015-01-01' as Date) 
         AND CAST('2015-05-30' as Date)   
 ORDER BY table1.dateCreated DESC
```

Expected Output:

```
id | name | address | message |
```

note: assuming table 1 and table 2 have thousands of rows and table 3 has millions of rows

Comment: How much time does your query take to execute? I mean benchmark .

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 1,002 total, Query took 27.2299 sec) based on phpmyadmin.

Comment: Can you post an SQL Fiddle or a schema of your DB in the form of create tables, and insert statements with sample data?

Comment: Have you tried doing joining table 3 and using GROUP BY table1&2.columns then MAX(table3.message)?

Comment: That cast stuff seems unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your query

```
select 
t1.t1_id,
t1.name,
t2.address,
t3.message
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.t1_id = t2.t2_id
join table3 t3 on t3.logid = t1.t1_id
join(
  select max(logs) as logs,logid from table3
  where 
  message NOT LIKE "[ SYSTEM%" 
  group by logid
)x
on x.logs = t3.logs and x.logid = t3.logid
where 
t1.dateCreated BETWEEN CAST('2015-01-01' as Date) AND CAST('2015-05-30' as Date)
ORDER BY t1.dateCreated DESC;
```

Now you will need indexes on the tables, and I am assuming ids of all the 
tables are primary key and are indexed so no need to add additional indexes on them.
The following index would be needed

```
alter table table3 add index logs_idx(logs);
alter table table3 add index message_idx(message);
alter table table3 add index logid_idx(logid);

alter table table1 add index dateCreated_idx(dateCreated);
```

NOTE : Make sure to take a table backup before applying the indexes.

Comment: hi. i will run the query above after creating the necessary index?.

Comment: sorry im just a beginner :)

Comment: yes first create the indexes and before that take a backup of the table. Then run the queries and see the performace.

Comment: tnx.. from 1,002 total, Query took 27.2299 sec) to  1,176 total, Query took 1.8409 sec :D

Answer (score 0):

Is it any faster like this ?

```
SELECT table1.t1_id, table1.name,table2.address, m.message 
FROM 
table3 as m, 
table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.t1_id = table2.t2_id
WHERE table1.dateCreated
BETWEEN CAST('2015-01-01' as Date) AND CAST('2015-05-30' as Date)
and m.logid = table1.t1_id
and m.message not like "[ SYSTEM%"
having min(m.log)
ORDER BY table1.dateCreated DESC
```

Comment: Error:  #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: can you post some sample table data ?

Comment: can you post some sample data please (ahem, third time asking cough cough)

Comment: I ask you to post sample data so i can put it in fiddle and then i can get it working before i post an answer.

Comment: just a small sample is fine,  5 or so rows from each table involved .   and make sure if there are relational links between the tables that the ID's or whatever data linking them matches up like it would in the real database.

Comment: and you don't have to space out the whole thing, you can just write it as insert statements if that's easier.  accompanies by create table statements of course would be helpful as well.